# Cannot add subdomain after editing vhost templates in DirectAdmin

Tags: subdomain, virtualhost

## Issue

I have a virtual private server running Debian with DirectAdmin.

I have edited the vhost template files used by DirectAdmin so that subdomains aren't placed in the main domain's `public_html`. As per the [instructions](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=2), I have asked DirectAdmin to rewrite the vhosts, which it did. After adjusting the directory structures, all sites work like a charm.

However, adding new domains builds the default directory structure and adding subdomains spits out an error.

## Detailed description

Let me explain in detail. Here's the docroots my custom templates create.

virtual_host2.conf:

```
|?DOCROOT=`HOME`/domains/`DOMAIN`/www/public_html|
```

virtual_host2_sub.conf:

```
|?DOCROOT=`HOME`/domains/`DOMAIN`/`SUB`/public_html|
```

After creating the domain test.pl, I get the following (incorrect) directories:

```
/home/myuser/domains/test.pl/.htpasswd
/home/myuser/domains/test.pl/public_ftp
/home/myuser/domains/test.pl/public_html
```

and the vhost entry lists the following (correct) docroot:

```
DocumentRoot /home/myuser/domains/test.pl/www/public_html
```

Adding a subdomain works the same - old incorrect directory structure is created, but the vhost uses the new, correct template. After I correct the domain's directory structure:

```
/home/myuser/domains/test.pl/www/.htpasswd
/home/myuser/domains/test.pl/www/public_ftp
/home/myuser/domains/test.pl/www/public_html
```

I try to add a subdomain again. This result in 3 errors and a failure to create the subdomain:

```
Error creating /home/myuser/domains/test.pl/public_html/mysub
A directory component in /home/myuser/domains/test.pl/public_html/mysub does not exist or is a dangling symbolic link

Error creating /home/myuser/domains/test.pl/public_html/mysub/cgi-bin
A directory component in /home/myuser/domains/test.pl/public_html/mysub/cgi-bin does not exist or is a dangling symbolic link

Error creating /home/myuser/domains/test.pl/private_html/mysub
A directory component in /home/myuser/domains/test.pl/private_html/mysub does not exist or is a dangling symbolic link
```

## Question

How to notify DirectAdmin of the new directory structure when creating domains and subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your VHost template won't make DirectAdmin create the directory structure you want, it will only make Apache set a different document root for that domain or subdomain.

You might want to take a look at [this](http://www.directadmin.com/features.php?id=183) and [this other feature](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=187).

As you can see there, you can write a custom script to be executed after creating a domain or subdomain so that it creates the directory structure you want.

For example, if it is for a subdomain you could create the script `/usr/local/directadmin/scripts/custom/subdomain_create_post.sh` with something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -rf /home/$username/domains/$domain/public_html/$subdomain
mkdir -p /home/$username/domains/$domain/$subdomain/public_html
chown $username:$username /home/$username/domains/$domain/$subdomain/public_html
exit 0;
```

Comment: I don't exactly see how I can achieve what I'm after; would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: @mingos I edited my answer, please check it out now.

Comment: The problem is that the directory `public_html/$subdomain` is not created at all because `public_html` does not exist. The issue is that creating the subdomain fails. This would only work for me if I decided to have domains in `domains/$domain/public_html` and subdomains in `domains/$subdomain.$domain/public_html` or similar. Thanks for pointing out the method though as it might be very useful for configuring my clients' servers ;).

Comment: Oh, wait, with *_create_pre, I can temporarily create the public_html... alright, seems you saved the day! Thanks, mate!